# In flexbox each element occupies the size according to its content, why is it passed to another line the content in some cases?

Tags: css, flexbox

I was trying something simple but I do not know what I'm doing wrong. I have 2 articles and I would like to respect the size of the second article, the text is put in another line. I would like for the first article the content to be put in other lines, but the one in the second article occupies the necessary to not be shown in the second line.

This question is to understand a little more flexbox and get a solution using it.

```css
section {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  order: solid 1px black;
}

.box1 {
  background: red;
}

.box2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article class="box1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum dolore quae at provident libero eum, nulla laborum eaque aliquid quos modi, ex, qui officia est possimus. Maiores asperiores sunt quo.
  </article>
  <article class="box2">
    caja 2
  </article>
</section>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the second div to shrink by adding `flex-shrink:0`:

> The flex-shrink CSS property specifies the flex shrink factor of a
>   flex item. **Flex items will shrink to fill the container according to**
>   **the flex-shrink number**, when the default size of **flex items is larger**
>   than the flex container.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)</sup>

```css
section{
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;

  border: solid 1px black;
}

.box1{
  background:red;
}
.box2{
  background:yellow;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article class="box1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum dolore quae at provident libero eum, nulla laborum eaque aliquid quos modi, ex, qui officia est possimus. Maiores asperiores sunt quo.
  </article>
  <article class="box2">
  this one will be kept in one line
  </article>
</section>
```

So basically both items will overflow the container if there is no flex shrink:

```css
section{
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;

  border: solid 1px black;
}

.box1{
  background:red;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
.box2{
  background:yellow;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article class="box1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum dolore quae at provident libero eum, nulla laborum eaque aliquid quos modi, ex, qui officia est possimus. Maiores asperiores sunt quo.
  </article>
  <article class="box2">
  caja 2
  </article>
</section>
```

Since by default `flex-shrink` is set to `1` both items will shrink equally to fit their parent container thus your content will be moved to a new line. The trick here is to allow only the first item to shrink by disabling the shrink effect on the second one.

Here is a [useful link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Controlling_Ratios_of_Flex_Items_Along_the_Main_Ax) to better understand the flexbox algorithm and how `flex-shrink` affect the layout.

Comment: Can you please explain to me in this case what happens when you apply flex-shrink? I understood that flex-shrink is used to shrink an element with respect to others. Excuse my ignorance, but I'm very interested in understanding it.

Comment: @yavg I added more details ;) basically all the element will shrink by default but using 0 as a value you avoid this

Comment: I think I should do the opposite, I should shrink the article but in this case it makes it grow. It is not clear to me

Comment: @yavg what you want is that the second article doesn't go to a new line so you don't want this one to shrink its size, that why I added `flex-shrink:0` (0 means don't shrink) but the first one should shrink and we don't need to add anything since by default flex-shrink is equal to 1

Comment: can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584770/how-to-put-a-fixed-element-so-that-the-text-is-put-under-it-using-flex-box

Answer (score -1):

You just need to set the width of boxes

>

```css
section{
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  /* flex-direction:row; */
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.box1{
  background:red;
  width:50%;
}
.box2{
  background:yellow;
  width:50%
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article class="box1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum dolore quae at provident libero eum, nulla laborum eaque aliquid quos modi, ex, qui officia est possimus. Maiores asperiores sunt quo.
  </article>
  <article class="box2">
  caja 2
  </article>
</section>
```