# Wrapping elements with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I just did a flexbox course and I'm practicing, so I would appreciate if the answer involves flexbox concepts. I have 2 article elements, and I would like the second article to be always in that position, the text of the first article can be put under it. However, the size of each article is currently respected, how can I fix this? Here is my current HTML and CSS along with a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ecoh9n1/) of it:

```
<section>
  <article class="box1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta dolorum ad perferendis eligendi inventore quo deserunt omnis impedit culpa blanditiis, sapiente pariatur a totam cumque, odit incidunt ipsum delectus provident. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit dignissimos, quos id rerum doloremque, dicta odio et perspiciatis officia dolorum amet quaerat doloribus ea sequi porro odit tenetur pariatur. Placeat.
  </article>
  <article class="box2">caja 2</article>
</section>

section {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.box1 {
  background: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.box2 {
  background: yellow;
  align-self: flex-start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Additionally I've created an image to visualize what I want:

[image: There are examples of two elements in a row interact with each other. In the first example, the left element's text wraps around the smaller element to the right. This is marked as correct with a checkmark. In aA second example they are in their own columns and as such, they don't wrap.]

Comment: For future reference this is called wrapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do such thing with flexbox, this is a use case of [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float):

```css
section {
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.box1 {
  background: red;
}

.box2 {
  background: yellow;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article class="box2">caja 2</article>
  <article class="box1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta dolorum ad perferendis eligendi inventore quo deserunt omnis impedit culpa blanditiis, sapiente pariatur a totam cumque, odit incidunt ipsum delectus provident. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit dignissimos, quos id rerum doloremque, dicta odio et perspiciatis officia dolorum amet quaerat doloribus ea sequi porro odit tenetur pariatur. Placeat.
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: friend excuse me, I forgot to include an image to explain myself better. I updated the question

Comment: @yavg for this situation you cannot use flexbox, you need to rely on float [updated]

Comment: in the previous example you used margin-left: 0 auto; in this case float: rigth. why? Thank you very much I learned a lot thanks to you.

Comment: @yavg I used margin-left:auto to align it to the right [here is the old code : https://jsfiddle.net/3oejf0pL/] as this is a common way to align element using flexbox but it won't be enough for what you need because what you need is float in this case.